# How to assign variable variables in Python3 based on another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am working on building an AI in Python3 to play Starcraft II using python-sc2 in [BurnySC2](https://github.com/BurnySc2/python-sc2) . How do I concisely assign values to different variables based on another variable? I've kicked around a few things, but none of them seem to do what I want. All of the buildings and units are stored as a *UnitTypeId* with different names for similar unit/building types based on the race.

For instance, I want to do something like:

```
ai_race = 1

def ai_tech_tree(ai_type)
    switcher = {
        Race.1: ai_townhall = UnitTypeId.townhall1;
            ai_worker = UnitTypeId.worker1;
            ai_fighter = UnitTypeId.fighter1,
        Race.2: ai_townhall = UnitTypeId.townhall2;
            ai_worker = UnitTypeId.worker2;
            ai_fighter = UnitTypeId.fighter2
    }

ai_tech_tree(ai_race)

class MyBot(BotAI): # inherits from BotAI
    async def on_step(self, iteration: int): # method called every step of the game
        if self.townhalls:  # does AI have a townhall?
            town_hall = self.townhalls.random  # select random AI-owned townhall
            if town_hall.is_idle and self.can_afford(ai_worker):  # is AI's townhall idle and can AI afford a worker?
                town_hall.train(ai_worker)  # train a worker
```

but you can't seem to declare a variable in the *CASES* statement. The closest I got to something that at least worked is doing a *CASES* for each unit/building type, but that was large and clunky.

```
ai_race = 1

def get_ai_townhall(ai_type)
    switcher = {
        Race.1: UnitTypeId.townhall1,
        Race.2: UnitTypeId.townhall2,
        Race.3: UnitTypeId.townhall3
        ...
    }

def get_ai_worker(ai_type)
    switcher = {
        Race.1: UnitTypeId.worker1,
        Race.2: UnitTypeId.worker2,
        Race.3: UnitTypeId.worker3
        ...
    }

...

ai_townhall = get_ai_townhall(ai_race)
ai_worker = get_ai_worker(ai_race)
...
```

I am hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) what you are looking for?

Comment: @wwii maybe. I'd need to dig into that documentation to know for sure.

Comment: setattr() very well may be the answer, but I cannot figure out how to make it work the way I need. At least not yet.